# Does the testicle's temperature increases with the body temperature during a high fever?

Tags: general-biology

The testes is the male sexual organ. It is positioned outside the abdomen along with the scrotum. I would like to know if its temperature is independent from the body temperature due to its location.

Comment: Welcome to health SE:-) Sorry but I'm not actually getting your question correctly. Pls can you make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score -1):

The question is quite vague. Please specify for clear answer.
However, although testicles are out of the body, but a part for sure. Due to pyrogen attack when the body temperature increases, literally the temperature of the testicles should be increased but clear research has not been found yet. 
Please specify your question.